# SELECT IN for a large set

Tags: sql, select

In my web application, I want to find out which of a user's friends on Twitter are already existing on the system... Currently what I am doing is getting the list of Twitter IDs the user is following (Twitter API returns the IDs 5000 at a time), and doing:

```
SELECT userId FROM users WHERE userId IN (COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_IDs);
```

I don't feel comfortable about this query, because as the users table grows, this might prove to be a bottle neck. I don't want to optimize prematurely either, so is there any other way I should be doing this?

**Update:** I am using MySQL.

Comment: Do you really mean *how many* or do you actually mean *which*?

Comment: I meant which, edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches:

1. `SELECT IN (expr)` is able to have a `SELECT` expression for `expr`. I.e. the database can handle a large amount of data here.
2. Use a join.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new table, and begin storing all of the twitter id's that your users are following.  Then, determining who is already in your system would be a simple join on indexed columns.  You can use the Twitter API to load and update that table at your discretion.

Comment: Would the overhead of creating a temporary table, performing the join and then deleting it better than using SELECT IN (expr) where expr might have upto 5000 values? I don't currently have the need to maintain the follow table on a permanent basis.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the temporary table option to occur every time this is checked, but you're welcome to test it out and see how it performs.  Though you don't need to store that follow data permanently, I think you'll find little reason not to hold on to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that users.userId is your primary key. If so, it will already be indexed, so the lookup should already be efficient. Do you expect that your COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_IDS will grow beyond reason?

Comment: Twitter gives userIds in 5k batches in case the user follows more than 5000 people. So, COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_IDS will be maximum 5000 IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EXISTS function if this is Transact SQL. I'm not sure if EXISTS works in other databases because I only work in SQL Server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx